# how to improve query using rails and postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have three models `posts`has one for  `post_rating`, `post_waiting_time`

`post.rb`

```
name_column      type           example 
id               integer           20
name             string           'welcome'
user_id          integer           1
```

`post_rating.rb`

```
name_column      type           example 
id               integer           10
rating_label     enum           poor,average,great
post_id          integer           20
```

`post_waiting_time.rb`

```
name_column      type           example 
id               integer           10
waiting_label     enum           0-3,4-6,7-10
post_id          integer           20
```

i try use rating_label, waiting_label in query use `eager_load`, `joins`  but can't write multi label in query

```
posts_lists = user.posts.eager_load(:post_rating, :post_waiting_time).where("post_waiting_times.waiting_label = ? ", '0-3')
```

this query work good with one value but i need multi query use waiting_label for example `0-3, 4-7` i try use `IN() but i have error`

```
Post.eager_load(:post_rating, :post_waiting_time).where('post_waiting_times.waiting_label IN( ? )', 'more_30,0-
3')
```

error message for last query

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input value for enum tag_label: "more_30,0-3")
LINE 1: ...ERE (post_waiting_times.waiting_label IN( 'more_30,0...
```

i fix this with
write query for filter by `rating_label`, `waiting_label`

```
posts_lists = user.posts
posts_lists.each do |record|
        flag_filter = false
        unless waiting_filter.empty?
          flag_filter = if waiting_filter.include?(record.post_waiting_time.waiting_label)
                          true
                        else
                          false
                        end
        end

        unless rating_filter.empty?
          flag_filter = if rating_filter.include?(record.post_rating.rating_label)
                          true
                        else
                          false
                        end
        end
    if flag 
       puts record
    end
```

but this not efficiency way

i use `Rails 6`, `PostgreSQL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you can directly pass an array for comparison in rails. Here is the updated query

```
Post.eager_load(:post_rating, :post_waiting_time).where(post_waiting_times: {waiting_label: ['more_30','0-3']})
```

Hope this solves the problem.